# Breadcrumbs Design Pattern

Tags: asp.net, design-patterns, yahoo

I was reading about the [breadcrumbs design pattern](http://developer.yahoo.com/ypatterns/navigation/breadcrumbs.html) at the Yahoo design patterns website.

They say that we should `never display a breadcrumb on the site's topmost page`.  Are they talking about the default page (landing page) of the site in the root directory?  Is this topmost page just 1 page, or it is for every default page (if a directory structure is used)?

Please provide samples :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're talking about the topmost page on a conceptual level. The page that users would likely think is the "home page". Where it's addressed or situated physically is not relevant, although in most cases it will be the root.

A great majority of websites can be thought of as a tree, with a single root node as the "home page". Top-level categories/navigation points ("directories" in your question) could be the first level of branches from the root, in which case they will have breadcrumbs to the root.